# GtkPopover and applet

Tags: applet, gtk, linux-mint, cinnamon

How to write code in `on_applet_clicked` function that show `GtkPopover` with example content? `gtk_popover_new ()` and what next with this?

```
const Applet = imports.ui.applet;
const Util = imports.misc.util;

function MyApplet(orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
    this._init(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
}

MyApplet.prototype = {
    __proto__: Applet.IconApplet.prototype,

    _init: function(orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
        Applet.IconApplet.prototype._init.call(this, orientation, panel_height, instance_id);

        this.set_applet_icon_name("folder-system");
        this.set_applet_tooltip(_("Click here to kill a window"));
    },

    on_applet_clicked: function() {
        // here
    }
};

function main(metadata, orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
    return new MyApplet(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use GTK+ within the Cinnamon window manager UI elements.

GTK+ is a client-side, application toolkit; it cannot be used inside a window manager.

If you want to use a menu for an applet, you'll have to use a `PopupMenu` instance by importing it as:

```
const PopupMenu = imports.ui.popupMenu;
```

and populate it with `PopupMenuItem` instances and their subclasses.